# Arbitrary python names with slashes in import statement

Tags: python, syntax, import, names

Gone through related questions,but cannot find this specific answer.

We're embedding python into our application, and have added a hook to sys.meta_path
to allow the import of arbitrarily named modules.
(That is, module definitions do not reside on disk, but are defined in memory *within* the package).

This allows things like:

```
import my_module_1#2#31421
```

or even:

```
__import__("my_module_1#2#31321")
```

The problem occurs when the specific label itself contains a slash.

```
import my_module_1/123/56
```

or

```
__import__("my_module_1/123/56")
```

It creates the following error, before even reading my meta_path hook.

**ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.**

Ive also tried things like:

```
import imp imp.load_source('my_module_1', '123/56')
```

But again, this does not even reach the meta_path hook.
The arbitrary names I need to pass are actually 'path' like, but do not refer to disk paths.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks very much,
Rob.

Comment: It seems to me this is an error in the python implementation, assuming that the name is a filename when it encounters slashes.  It should proceed through the regular mechanisms (meta_path hooks, etc) and report errors as usual. Don't understand this need for this presumptuous error?

Comment: Are they path-like enough that you could treat them as packages, have appropriate `__init__.py`s, and just use dot notation like you would with regular files?

Answer (score 0):

Well, an obvious workaround would be to use some different character in the sources, e.g. pipe, and have your hook replace such characters with slashes.  Depending on what exactly you need that would be more or less painful, though.

E.g.

```
import lol|foo
```

where the first line of your hook looks like

```
module_name = module_name.replace ('|', '/')
```

Comment: That would be a major hack throughout our scripting language.
Am I correct in assuming, this python error serves no purpose, as it wrongfully assumes Im passing in a filename, when it itself allows for modules that are not on disk?

Comment: Well, since this would normally be an error either way, probably yes.  I guess such things are better to discuss on CPython mailing list.  Unless you are willing to self-compile Python interpreter, I don't see a "proper" way around this error.

Comment: It wouldn't be an error either way, as the meta_path hook would correctly intercept and handle certain names without fail.  I'll ask on the cpython mailing list (I assume thats the best place for asking about changes?)  Thanks!

Comment: I meant it would be an error with standard environment (slashes are not allowed in standard Python module names, no?), therefore the more explicit error is superfluous.  If it was thrown after the hook had its say, then it would also be harmless.  Maybe CPython developers consider path-like slashes so bad of an idea they don't even want to let the hook to run, but more likely this is an oversight (e.g. Windows path backslash doesn't seem to be special-handled, at least on Linux).

Comment: Cool. I'll submit it to bugs.python.org and see what happens. Thanks for helping me clarify.